# Duda con implementación del patrón MVC en Java

Tags: java, mvc

tengo una duda con el patrón MVC.

Yo tengo una vista que me muestra los botones respectivos a un CRUD cliente. Bueno dentro de la vista tengo una instancia de clase con mi controlador.
Entonces cuando cuando se presiona un boton, me ejecuta un metodo, ese método llama al método correspondiente dentro de mi clase controladora ligada a esa vista con toda la lógica de la acción que se quiere realizar.

Pero no estoy seguro de si se aplica de esta manera el MVC. Vi muchos tutoriales en internet y algunos lo hacen de manera diferente.

Mi duda es, ¿Quién debe usar a quien? ¿El controlador a la vista, o la vista al controlador? Osea ¿Quién debe contener la instancia de quién?

Saludos.

Comment: Según el clásico MVC en Smalltalk. El usuario utiliza una interfaz para comunicarse con tu aplicación (teclado, mouse, etc) dichas acciones son traducidas por el _controlador_ en acciones concretas en el _modelo_ . La _vista_ debe subscribirse de manera indirecta al _,modelo_. Esto quiere decir que el _modelo_ notifica a los observadores un cambio en su estado. La _vista_ debe actualizarse por sí misma al notificársele algún cambio.

Comment: Así que respondiendo a tu duda: el modelo guarda las vistas a notificar, el controlador guarda la instacia del modelo al cuál realizar cambios y la vista utiliza un controlador para traducir las acciones del usuario en eventos del modelo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre instancio la vista en el controlador y la mayoría por no decir todos los programadores que conozco también lo hacen así . Pero eso no quiere decir que instanciar el controlador en la vista este mal . Yo te recomiendo que lo hagas como a ti te guste más siempre y cuando el jefe/profesor no te diga lo contrario.

Comment: Esto es más un comentario que una respuesta, que no debe ir en esta zona si no en la parte de comentarios